# Openstack, ssh ubuntu instance: permission denied

Tags: ssh, openstack

I've installed devstack, downloaded a trusty ubuntu server image, launched a heat flavor instance, created a public ssh key, all fine.

But when trying to log in with `ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@ipAdress`
I got permission denied.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to get the provided ssh-key working.

So I created my own ssh-key and imported it to openstack - and that worked.